# DSE OpsCenter best practice fails when Cassandra PasswordAuthenticator is used

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

The following best practice checks fail when Cassandra's PasswordAuthenticator is enabled:

- Search nodes enabled with bad autocommit
- Search nodes enabled with query result cache
- Search nodes with bad filter cache

My values are in compliance with the recommended values; and I have confirmed that the checks indeed pass when I disable authentication in Cassandra. What's weird is that there are 6 checks under the "Solr Advisor" category of the Best Practice Service and only these 3 are failing when authentication is enabled.

[image]

Is this a known bug in Opscenter? I'm using v5.0.1 but I've seen this since v5.0.0.

Where can I file bug reports like this? Does Datastax have a public bug tracker?

**PS:**

I actually feel that this question is more appropriate under ServerFault but I don't have enough reputation in that site to create the tags "datastax" and "datastax-enterprise". Can somebody do so please and move this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Cassandra is using PasswordAuthenticator, then the http routes that opscenter agent uses to determine the solr schema settings also become password protected (however the agent does not try the password properly).  This is a bug in the opscenter agent, and can be referenced as OPSC-3605.

Unfortunately Datastax Enterprise does not have a public bug tracker.  If you're a DSE customer, probably the best method you can use is to go through DSE support.

Comment: If that is the reason, then I don't understand why the other 3 checks are passing. See the image I included in my OP. The heap check is probably an exception because it is set through a different config file (cassandra-env.sh); but the other two are found in the same file where the 3 failing checks are set (solrconfig.xml). Were they implemented differently?

Comment: PS: The company that I work for is a DSE customer but only through the startup program - so we have no access to formal support. Would be good to be able to see existing bug reports, though

Comment: Hi PJ, actually those other checks are not coming from solrconfig.xml, they are coming from cassandra.yaml, please check that file for settings such as row_cache_size_in_mb.  If you're on the DSE startup program then forums such as StackOverflow are your best method for eliciting help.  You can refer to this as OPSC-3605 when communicating with Datastax.  Best.

Comment: PJ. can you send an email to startups@datastax.com? I will make sure you have a channel to take this kind of issue forward. Thank you!!!