# Can't perform inter-node administrative Solr commands when Cassandra PasswordAuthenticator is enabled

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Actions like core RELOAD/CREATE fail with the following message when Cassandra authentication is enabled:

> WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2014-10-22 02:09:26,355 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 310) Error creating core myks.mycf on node: /111.222.333.444
>    WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2014-10-22 02:09:26,357 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 310) Error creating core myks.mycf on node: /222.333.444.555
>    WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2014-10-22 02:09:26,360 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 310) Error creating core myks.mycf on node: /333.444.555.666
>    WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2014-10-22 02:09:26,365 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 310) Error creating core myks.mycf on node: /444.555.666.777
>    WARN [SolrDistributedRequestTemplate thread-0] 2014-10-22 02:09:26,368 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 310) Error creating core myks.mycf on node: /555.666.777.888

The same actions succeed when I disable authentication. Is this a known bug?

Probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013047/dse-opscenter-best-practice-fails-when-cassandra-passwordauthenticator-is-used)

**EDIT:**

My users and permissions:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.10.71 | DSE 4.5.2 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> select * from system_auth.users;

 name                                 | super
--------------------------------------+-------
 node682507b669a04443b3af75916a2ccd7d | False
 nodea41d1fc13e784e41ba0a925d95f26953 | False
 nodeba7fb6409207469db924db64841e9e9e | False
 node69d6ac2ff17348ca80ab00921c455440 | False
                            cassandra | False
 node98c907bc0f2b4225b3823616627ed309 | False
 node61a9d13323504e7b019c97292a1cdb6b | False
                            dse_admin |  True
```

The failing CREATE/RELOAD commands look something like:

```
curl -u dse_admin:password "http://111.222.333.444:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=myks.mycf"
```

Definition of `system_auth` keyspace:

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace system_auth;

CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'DC2': '3'
};
```

Definition of `myks` keyspace:

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace myks;

CREATE KEYSPACE myks WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'DC2': '2'
};
```

Comment: That should definitely work, please provide more details about your users and permissions.

Comment: Added those info into my OP

Comment: Everything looks correct, I also tried to reproduce by creating a core on a password protected two nodes cluster and it went fine. Are you sure you don't have any exceptions in the logs of the other nodes?

Comment: If your real password contains "#" it will fail, try doing curl -u dse_admin "http://111.222.333.444:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=myks.mycf" and the promt for password will be given.